# How do I validate a bind9 zone file?

Tags: domain-name-system

I want to validate zone files before adding them into my DNS server. Is there any applications or utilities that will allow me to do this. A Google didn't reveal anything useful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The utility you are after is called [`named-checkzone`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/named-checkzone).

It's distributed with BIND.