# Generate DNS zone redirecting subdomains to IP subnet

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, bind, dns-zone, ipv4

I created DNS zone as in example below. Is there another, clean way to redirect subdomains to IP address? Maybe with `bind9` `$GENERATE`? Can I use regex or iteration with existing DNS software? Where to start, and can DLZ (Dynamically Loadable Zones) solve that?

```
0-0 IN A 192.168.0.0
0-1 IN A 192.168.0.1
0-2 IN A 192.168.0.2
0-3 IN A 192.168.0.3

; ... SKIPPED 65k+ LINES

255-253 IN A 192.168.255.253
255-254 IN A 192.168.255.254
255-255 IN A 192.168.255.255
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure about your requirements.

---

**DLZ.**
`DLZ` are Dynamically Loadable Zones. 
[Per documentation](http://bind-dlz.sourceforge.net/), they allow to pull records from external driver.

```
dlz sample {
     database "dlopen driver.so <args>";
     [...]
};

zone "example.com" {
     type master;
     dlz sample
};
```

Said that, if you put your records in database; it is loading them from external database using `driver.so`.  Remember, it is more like a [*patch*](https://serverfault.com/questions/365434/configure-bind-with-database-backend-and-dlz-support); not a core functionality. 
It is also used as [integration with SAMBA.](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/BIND9_DLZ_DNS_Back_End) Such database *may* slow  response times from DNS server.

---

**Stable solution.** The fastest and the cleanest way for a moment is to manage [Zone as a file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto). You can easily generate them with templating system, [like Jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/), and deploy with [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) or [Salt](https://www.saltstack.com/). There are set or roles available on the Internet:

- [Turgon37/ansible-bind](https://github.com/Turgon37/ansible-bind),
- [bertvv/ansible-role-bind](https://github.com/bertvv/ansible-role-bind).

It will help you generate [reverse zone](https://www.apnic.net/about-apnic/corporate-documents/documents/resource-guidelines/reverse-zones/), [validate your records and syntax](https://serverfault.com/questions/83174/how-do-i-validate-a-bind9-zone-file) completely automatically.